# Why while querying ontologies we have to load the ontology, also provide its namespace?

Tags: namespaces, sparql, owl, ontology, rdflib

I wonder why we have to load an ontology, also provide its namespace while querying it? Why loading the ontology is not enough?

To understand my question better, here is a sample code:

```
g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse('ppp.owl', format='turtle')
ppp = rdflib.Namespace('http://purl.org/xxx/ont/ppp/')
g.bind('ppp', ppp)
```

In line 2, we have opened the ontology (ppp.owl), but in line 3 we also provided its namespace. Does namespace show the program how to handle the ontology?

Cheers,
RF

Comment: Who told you that you have to add a namespace? What you do with the lines is to declare a namespace prefix. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify an element over the semantic web you need its URI: **Unique Resource Identifier**, which is composed of the *namespace* and the *localname*. For example, consider `Person` an RDF class; how would you differentiate the `Person` DBpedia class `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person` from Person in some other ontology somewhere? you need the namespace `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` and the local name `Person`. Which both uniquely identify the class.

Now coming back to your specific question, when you query the ontology, you might use multiple namespaces, some namespaces may not be the one of your ontology. You need other namespaces for querying your own ontology, e.g. `rdf`, `rdfs`, and `owl`. As an example, you can rarely write an arbitrary query without `rdf:type` property, which is included under the `rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns>` namespace, not your ontology namespace. As a consequence, you need to specify the namespace.

Well, now as you should know why to use a namespace, then we can proceed. Why to repeat the whole string of the namespace each time it is needed?  It is nothing more than a prefix string appended to the local names to use in the query, to avoid writing exhaustively the full uri. See the difference between `<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>` and `type`.

**Edit**

As @AKSW says, as a conclusion, there is no need to declare a namespace in order to work with the ontology but it increases the convenience when working quite often with resources whose URI has particular namespace.

Comment: You should add as a conclusion that there is no need to declare a namespace in order to work with the ontology but it increases the convenience when working quite often with resources whose URI has particular namespace

Comment: added it to my answer

Comment: Thanks Median. It seems that I have not been clear with my question. I understand how to use namespaces and the reason we use them. But in this specific sample code, the programmer has loaded the ontology from a local file, also added it's namespace. It seems the code does not work without both defining the namespace and loading the file locally. Now my question is why this is the case? Why only one of them is not enough? Or maybe I am missing a point here? Thanks.

Comment: What that code allows is queries like 'select ?y where ?y rdf:type ppp:Test'. The ppp shortcut might not be the shortcut defined in the turtle file.

Comment: OK, so my question is why do we need to define a different shortcut (namespace) then? Is there a reason for that?